# Custom page pagination based on Kriesi pagination

Tags: pagination

I am stuck on this problem:

We have 2 custom post types on our website, both created the same way, only the name of the post type differs. In addition we have 2 custom page templates which show an archive of these custom post types.

Both use the same logic / look and feel only the custom post type posts shown differ.

Our problem is that we use custom pagination based on kriesi.at code. However for 1 custom page it works perfectly for the other one it isn't.

We did a diff of all code and cannot find the difference. And biggest problem is that we have absolutely no clue how to debug this since the only difference is the custom post type value...

Anyone suggestions on how to start debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when writing this question we suddenly thought that we did not try to change the permalink. After changing the permalink to another unique value it worked like a charm.

So still not sure what was causing this issue but the above solved the issue.

If anyone has a clue why the permalink was causing the problem please let us know, might help us by understanding the exact cause of the problem.